# Make debian package to install python

Tags: debian, python, packaging

I have two Python scripts, and I need to package them into a Debian package. I have tried quite a few things with some success. For example, I made a setup.py and then used `python-stdeb` to create a package (which - if I recall properly - did not work very well), and I also made my own package from scratch with a structure like so:

```
project
  DEBIAN/
    changelog
    copyright
    compat
    rules
    control
    install
  usr/
    bin/
      script1
      script2
```

It was something like that, anyway. I got a package that then acted like a Debian package and I could use `dpkg -b project` to first build it and then `dpkg -i package.deb` to install the Debian packaging, however it didn't install anything (well it did install some things, but it didn't install the scripts that I wrote, which is what I would really like to install). So, how can I just make a package that will install my Python scripts. I don't care if they go to X11 or I have to say "Install to `~/package`". All I want is for my scripts to go into a package so that someone else can install that package and have my scripts.

My guess is that I have to put metadata or something in the install file, but I don't know what to put in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One fast and easy way could be to use `alien`, it convert `.tar` to `.deb`:

```
tar czf pkg-name.tgz usr/
fakeroot alien -d pkg-name.tgz
```

Else use the old way, I use a Makefile like that:

```
all: deb

deb:
    mkdir -p tmp/usr/bin tmp/DEBIAN tmp/etc tmp/usr/share/man/man5
    find tmp -type d | xargs chmod 755
    cp some.conf tmp/etc/
    cp man/some.5 tmp/usr/share/man/man5/
    cp somecmd tmp/usr/bin/
    tar c --owner root --group root -v -z -f tmp/data.tar.gz -C tmp ./etc ./usr
    cd tmp && find usr/ etc/ -type f | xargs md5sum >DEBIAN/md5sums
    awk '/^#Package:/{i++}i {print substr($$0,2); }' Makefile >tmp/DEBIAN/control
    tar c --owner root --group root -v -z -f tmp/control.tar.gz -C tmp/DEBIAN ./control ./md5sums
    echo 2.0 >tmp/debian-binary
    ar rcv pkg-name_1.0-1.deb tmp/debian-binary tmp/control.tar.gz tmp/data.tar.gz

.phony: clean
clean:
    -rm -fr tmp

#Package: pkg-name
#Version: 1.0
#Section: net
#Priority: optional
#Architecture: all
#Essential: no
#Installed-size: 100
#Maintainer: Name <mail@here>
#Depends: optional dependencies
#Description: short descr
# long descr
```

Comment: huh, I saw that the other day. Since I didn't have a .tar file (just two scripts -- now three scripts and a PNG -- I didn't want to use it. I guess I could just `tar -cvzf` it. Not a bad idea. Again, I know basically nothing about Debian packages. My coworker just said "hey, make a package so I can download it on this headless wandboard." How would you "make" or build the make file (I'm assuming you *wouldn't* just do `make` `make install` or something like that. I like the make file idea, I just don't know what to do with it once I have it. Also, let me get back to you with the tar. Thanks!!!

Comment: Nice `alien` worked like a dream. That was a little too easy. The only thing it it installed to `/`. Any way to change that. (I honestly haven't looked around much for this on the internet yet, though.)

Comment: `tar+alien` are really easy, you must create and archive the relative path, ie: `./usr/bin/thescript`, `.deb`s are installed relative to `/`

Comment: Come again. I don't really understand what you are trying to say. I, of course, know what a relative path is, but I don't know what you mean by "create and archive the relative path." Do you mean that I must specify a relative path when I `tar` the package or when I use `alien` or something else entirely? Thanks

Comment: If you need to install `script` in `/usr/bin/` you've to `tar` `./usr/bin/script`

Comment: That is **the** weirdest thing I have seen thus far in Unix. What I did first was move my directory with my scripts and png to `/usr/bin/` then `cd`d to `/` then did `tar -zcvf ./usr/bin/dir_name`. Then I decided I wanted it to install to user's $HOME, so I did (assuming the directory with all your programs and stuff is in the home directory) `cd ~; tar -zcvf $HOME/dir_name.tar.gz dir_name; sudo alien --to-deb dir_name.tar.gz; rm -r dir_name; sudo dpkg -i dir_name_1-2_all.deb;` and it actually worked. That is really weird that you have to specify the path for *two* things at once though.

Comment: Will the installation to $HOME be portable? I've been thinking, and I am sure that the $HOME variable would probably get expanded. In that case, it would be /home/usrname so if someone else wanted to install this would it install to a new home/username for them or would it be smart enough to install to *their* home directory?